# Google Apps Scriptのエラーメッセージの意味

Tags: google-apps-script

Googleスプレッドシートを編集するバッチ処理のGoogleAppsScript運用していましたが、先日から下記のエラーメッセージのメールが届くようになり、動作しなくなってしまいました。

- サービスで 1 日に使用しているコンピュータ時間が長すぎます
- 起動時間の最大値を超えました

不具合を修正したいのですが、エラーの意味が分からずに対処に困っています。

どういった時に発生するものなにかを教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: ユーザーの種類によって使用上限がありますので、その上限に達したんだと思います。私は利用してないのでよくわかりませんが[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)で該当する項目がないか調べてみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます！回答を更新します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ユーザの種類によって使用時間、一度の処理の事項時間に上限があるのでそれが達したみたいです。

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas